# How to programmatically search from excel (xlsx) file in c# if using OfficeOpenXml to read data from excel?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, epplus

I have written a code previously which was used to  find a item from excel file in which previously i was using microsoft.interop dll to find data but now i currently needed to use any other opensource excel reading library so want to change its functions/methods to that library  suitable methods.
I have thought to use OfficeOpenXml EPPlus library to read data from excel if there's any other library i can use for finding data from excel then i can use that one as well needed code changes help for that particular library.

```
     private int DemoFind(Excel.Range xlRange,string value)
    {
        Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Excel.Range firstFind = null;

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // You should specify all these parameters every time you call this method,
        // since they can be overridden in the user interface. 
        currentFind = xlRange.Find(value,missing,
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,false,missing,missing);

        while (currentFind != null)
        {
            // Keep track of the first range you find. 
            if (firstFind == null)
            {
                firstFind = currentFind;
            }

            // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
            else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                  == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
            {
                return currentFind.Row;
                
            }

            

            currentFind = xlRange.FindNext(currentFind);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Need to change this particular code the methods used are based from Microsoft Interop dll needed methods from different library like OfficeOpenXml EPPlus.